# Очень странный баг при работе с XML файлом. Как его исправить?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Регулярно работаю с PHP/Delphi/CSharp и такого бага там не встречал. Так что немного удивлен.

Unity 2021.3. - тестовый проект, специально созданный для тестирования этого бага.

Моя задача элементарна - записать в xml файл значение, а потом прочитать его оттуда.

Итого в проекте - одна сцена, 3 кнопки, 3 скрипта.

**Скрипт XMLReader.cs - читает данные их XML файла**

```cs
public static class XMLReader
{
    
    public static string GetXMLValue(string pathToXMLFile, string NodeName1, string NodeName2)
    {  
        TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(pathToXMLFile);
        
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(textAsset.text);
        
        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(NodeName1+"/"+NodeName2);
        string nodeValue = node.InnerText;
        
        return nodeValue;
    }
}
```

**XMLWriter.cs - пишет данные в XML файл**

```cs
public static class XMLWriter
{
    
    public static void SetXMLValue(string pathToXMLFile, string nodeName1, string nodeName2, string nodeName2Value)
    {
        TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(pathToXMLFile);
        
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(textAsset.text);
        
        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/"+nodeName1+"/"+nodeName2);
        node.InnerText = nodeName2Value;
        
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/"+pathToXMLFile+".xml", xmlDoc.OuterXml);
    }
}
```

**Скрипт SetGameLanguageScript - обработчик, повешенный на кнопки для вызова скрипта записи и скрипта чтения.**

```cs
public class SetGameLanguageScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject gameLanguageTextObject;
    private Text gameLanguageText;
       
    private void Start()
    {
        gameLanguageTextObject = GameObject.Find("GameLanguageText");
        gameLanguageText = gameLanguageTextObject.GetComponent<Text>(); 
    }
    
    // Прочитать значение из XML файла и вывести его в текст на сцене.    
    public void ReadXMLButtonButtonClick()
    {
        gameLanguageText.text = XMLReader.GetXMLValue("GameSettings", "GameSettings", "game_language");
        Debug.Log("Клик по кнопке чтения значения из XML");
        Debug.Log("gameLanguageText.text="+gameLanguageText.text);
    }
    
    // Записать в XML файл значение RU.       
    public void WriteRUXMLButtonButtonClick()
    {
        XMLWriter.SetXMLValue("GameSettings", "GameSettings", "game_language","RU");
        Debug.Log("Клик по кнопке записи значения RU в XML");
    }
     
     // Записать в XML файл значение ENG.
    public void WriteENGMLButtonButtonClick()
    {
        XMLWriter.SetXMLValue("GameSettings", "GameSettings", "game_language","ENG");
        Debug.Log("Клик по кнопке записи значения ENG в XML");
    }
}
```

**А теперь самое интересное.**

Запуск сцены из редактора юнити:

- При нажатии кнопки записи в xml файл, а потом чтения из xml файла - ничего не происходит и текст не изменяется.
- При нажатии кнопки записи в xml файл и переключении с Unity на любое другое окно, приложение (калькулятор например) а потом чтения из xml файла - текст изменяется.
  Порядок что и когда нажали не важен - главное переключиться на другое окно или приложение.

Запуск сцены build and run или запуск готового exe файла приложения:

- смены текста не происходит, даже переключении на другое приложение. В xml файле значение не изменяется.

Антивирус отключал. В папке Assets\Resources размещал простой текстовый файл и писал туда, читал оттуда WriteAllText(filePath, "ENG");. Всё прекрасно работает - пишет и читает.

Видео с багом
https://youtu.be/QAqa9YHL2Go

Что это за баг и как его исправить?

Comment: Почему не используете `PlayerPrefs`?

Comment: `Resources.Load` это единственная строчка относящаяся к `Unity3D`. Почему вы вообще используете `XML`? Все работают с `Json` и в `Unity3D` для этого есть простенькая утилита `JsonUtility`. Сохранять простые значения или модели в файл тоже не нужно, для этого есть `PlayerPrefs`, удобная для всех платформ.